# Setting node labels with a parameter

Tags: neo4jclient

I'm trying to pile a load of Twitter data into Neo4J using the .Net Neo4JClient. It's essentially the same type of Twitter user data for each node, but some of the nodes have a different significance to others, hence I would like to label them differently.

(I'm brand new both to Neo4J and the client, too).

So I've been trying to label them like so:

```
var query = _client.Cypher
              .Create("(primaryNode:nodeLabel {twitterUser})")
              .WithParams(new { nodeLabel = "nodeType", twitterUser } );


query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Note: I split out the ExecuteWithoutResults so I could debug the query, and it is registering the parameters OK. The documentation here:

https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#explicit-parameters

... suggests that parameters can be created "at any point in the fluent query" - but the Neo documentation about parameters here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.2/cypher-parameters.html

... kind of suggests otherwise, that parameters are specifically for things like WHERE clauses, indexes and relationship Ids.

Anyway - when I execute the above, I get a shiny new node with the label "nodeLabel" - so the parameter ain't working. Could somebody clarify whether or not I'm just making a dumb newbie mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `WithParams` whenever you want in the query. That's what the Neo4jClient doco means about "at any point in the ***fluent*** query".

However, Neo4j only supports parameters in certain parts of the Cypher text. If the parameter would affect the query plan, it's not allowed.

In this case, you cannot use parameters for labels. You will need to actually construct the query dynamically if you want to do that.

**Edit:** Even if this was a supported place for parameters, you'd at least have to write `{nodeLabel}` in your Cypher instead of just `nodeLabel`.

Comment: Thanks for the last edit. I had tried wrapping the "nodeLabel parameters" (which I now know aren't supported) in braces but it still didn't work. I was a little confused initially by the Neo4JClient documentation about parameters and braces, but reading up the Neo4J documentation about parameters clarified that those areas of a  Cypher query that accept parameters are in braces in the raw Cypher, so the Neo4JClient just mirrors that with its query syntax. (I think?)

Comment: From what I gather - labels are a 2.0 feature that the Neo4J people still have plenty of work to do upon, aren't they? So perhaps parameterisation of them in Cypher queries is on the upcoming feature list?

Comment: Neo4jClient is just passing that Syntax straight down to Neo4j, without changing it.

Labels are mature, but they don't make sense with parameterisation. Parameters can't affect the query plan, otherwise they are half way to pointless. Labels do have to affect the query plan, otherwise they are half way to pointless.