# How to create a node with variable label?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

It seems I'm unable to create a node with a label based on userinput. I would like to store posted userinput from a form in a variable and pass it on to a Cypher query. While this seems to work fine for properties, it doesn't for labels. I've spend half a day on every possibility like:

```
('CREATE n:{typeParam} {desc:{descParam}, userID: {IDParam}}) RETURN n', {typeParam:type, descParam: desc, userID: id})

('CREATE n (SET n:{typeParam} {desc:{descParam}, userID: {IDParam}}) RETURN n', {typeParam:type, descParam: desc, userID: id})

('CREATE n:($typeParam) {desc:{descParam}, userID: {IDParam}}) RETURN n', {typeParam:type, descParam: desc, userID: id})
```

The first character of the the label variable is always seen as invalid input. I really wonder how to do this.

Comment: I dont think that's possible. Please look at the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701186/setting-node-labels-with-a-parameter), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957497/unable-to-set-node-label-dynamically-using-the-neo4j-rest-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274364/in-neo4j-how-to-set-the-label-as-a-parameter-in-a-cypher-query-from-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`apoc.create.node`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) procedure from the [`APOC library`](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures):

```
CALL apoc.create.node(
  // array of labels
  [{typeParam}],

  // property object
  {
    desc: {descParam}, 
    usedID: {userID}
  } 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and showing the APOC library. I realized this question might be a duplicate when asking. I know I am a beginner programmer, but still, it felt weird to accept something is impossible.

Comment: hi! but what if for each node there should be different labels? If I have an array of objects in each object I have the label and node data, Is there a way to iterate through array and create nodes with it's own labels ?

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan Try using UNWIND with your array of objects [https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/]

Comment: @stdob-- Hi and thx. I used unwind with apoc.merge.node. It works good but in case of nulls I get error in neo4j (java.lang.NullPointerException). Is there a way to handle nulls in neo4j ?

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan Hi, I think you need to create a new question with a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example